# Sed and Awk learning material

Tags: command-line, sed, awk

I'm looking for some learning material for sed and awk, can anyone make any suggestions?

Please don’t refer to man and help pages.

-O-

Answer (score 1):

You may like this resource: http://www.catonmat.net/books/ It gives a very good overview of what can be done, and with examples.